# Delphi and quickbooks examples

Tags: delphi, sdk, quickbooks

We have created a delphi app to connect to quickbooks 11 pro. 
We are trying to use BeginSession from the TLB file and it works fine when creating a new company but after restoring a file from one of our clients, which might have been from a newer release it won't connect. But QB doesn't give any error messages, is there a way to make this happen ?

Thanks

Andy

Comment: You don't say what kind of info you are trying to extract from an existing QB company file. There are a few third party products that will enable you to create a database comprised of QB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Download the QuickBooks SDK if you haven't already done so, then try using the SDKTestPlus3 tool to see if it can access the company file.  If it can't the problem is probably with the company file, if it can the problem is probably with your program.